# Compare 2 dataframes in Apache Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have 2 datasets:

Dataset1:

```
CustID  CustName    CustRegion  
1       Joe         Canada  
2       Jane        UK
```

Dataset2:

```
CustID   CustName   CustCity    CustPrice
1        Joe        Berlin      20
2        Jane       UK          11
3        Bill       France      30
```

Want to get output as below after joining both dataframes:

```
CustID  CustName        CustRegion      CustCity            CustPrice
1       Joe             Canada          (null, Berlin)      (null, 20)
2       Jane            UK              (null, UK)          (null, 11)
3       (null, Bill)    (null, null)    (null, France)      (null, 30)
```

I tried to use below code but get error for using the ... when:

```
val cols = df1.columns.filter(_ != "CustID").toList

// function to create an expression that results in null for similar values,
// and with a two-item array with the differing values otherwise
def mapDiffs(name: String) = {
  when($"df1.$name" === $"df2.$name", df2.$name)
    .otherwise(array($"l.$name", $"r.$name"))
    .as(name)
}

// joining the two DFs on OrgId
val result = df1.as("l")
  .join(targetDF.as("r"), "CustID")
  .select($"CustID" :: cols.map(mapDiffs): _*)

result.show()
```

Comment: Not convinced it is consistent, 3(null,null)

Answer (score 0):

I see two errors in your attempt

1. you have aliased dataframes as `l` and `r` but in the function you used
   `df1` and `df2`
2. the conditions in the functions are not enough for the expected
   output dataframe

Here's a possible solution . I have created temporary dataframes as mentioned in the question and commented each part for explanation and clarity

```
//creating temporary dataframes for testing
val df1 = Seq(
  ("1", "Joe", "Canada"),
  ("2", "Jane", "UK")
).toDF("CustID", "CustName", "CustRegion")

val targetDF = Seq(
  ("1", "Joe", "Berlin", "20"),
  ("2", "Jane", "UK", "11"),
  ("3", "Bill", "France", "30")
).toDF("CustID", "CustName", "CustCity", "CustPrice")

//selecting column names of both dataframe without CustID
val cols1 = df1.columns.filter(_ != "CustID").toList
val cols2 = targetDF.columns.filter(_ != "CustID").toList

//all column names without duplicates expect CustID of both dataframes
val allCols = cols1 ++ cols2 toSet

//extra columns needed for both dataframes columns to be same
val extraColsDf1 = allCols -- cols1
val extraColsTargetDf = allCols -- cols2

//adding the extra columns and populating with null
val tempDf1 = extraColsDf1.foldLeft(df1){(temp, c) => temp.withColumn(c, lit(null))}
val tempTargetDf = extraColsTargetDf.foldLeft(targetDF){(temp, c) => temp.withColumn(c, lit(null))}

//function for getting your desired output
def mapDiffs(name: String) = {
  when($"l.$name".isNull && $"r.$name".isNull, concat_ws(",", lit("null"), lit("null")))  // for outputs like null,null
      .otherwise(when($"r.$name".isNull, $"l.$name")  //for outputs like Canada and UK
        .otherwise(when($"l.$name".isNull, concat_ws(",", lit("null"), $"r.$name")) //for outputs like null,Bill
        .otherwise(when($"l.$name" === $"r.$name" && $"l.$name".isNotNull && $"r.$name".isNotNull, $"l.$name")  // for outputs like Joe
          .otherwise(concat_ws(",", $"l.$name", $"r.$name"))  //for rest of the outputs
        )
      )
    )
    .as(name)
}

// outer joining the two DFs on CustID and calling the above function
val result = tempDf1.as("l")
  .join(tempTargetDf.as("r"), Seq("CustID"), "outer")
  .select(Seq($"CustID") ++ allCols.map(mapDiffs): _*)

//showing the output
result.show(false)
```

which should give you

```
+------+---------+----------+-----------+---------+
|CustID|CustName |CustRegion|CustCity   |CustPrice|
+------+---------+----------+-----------+---------+
|3     |null,Bill|null,null |null,France|null,30  |
|1     |Joe      |Canada    |null,Berlin|null,20  |
|2     |Jane     |UK        |null,UK    |null,11  |
+------+---------+----------+-----------+---------+
```

You can modify according to your needs

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: Ramesh, thanks for your help. I am getting error when using "$" as in the function mapDiffs(name: String). I already imported below packages and I am getting the dataframes straight which aren't created from Spark SQL. These dataframes were created from CSV files. Pls help ...

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.when
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.concat_ws
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

Tried to use <col> but its not working.

Comment: did you `import sqlContext.implicits._` inside the context's scope or `import sparkSession.implicits._` if you are using higher version of spark?

Comment: or instead of `$"l.$name"` or `$"r.$name"` you can using col as `col(s"l.$name")` or `col(s"r.$name")`

Comment: Thanks Ramesh, this helps. Apologies for late reply.

Comment: if the answer is helpful you can accept it as an answer and upvote too @Voila